# Wordpress Theme "MarryMe" - dropdown menu hides when I try to click the last result on Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I have a problem on Wordpress on Chrome browser.

When I open main page or one of the other - everything is fine.

But when I open blog page, contact page and others, there is a problem with dropdown menu which is shown when you hover 'Oferta' Page. The dropdown menu contains a few options and when I try to click the last one at the bottom, the menu disappears which makes it impossible to click on this last option. I'm not a technical person so don't really know what to show you to help you.

Maybe layout.css with a sub-menu css? If so, here it is:

```css
ul#left-primary.primary-menu li a {
    /*padding: 14px 13px 16px;*/
}
ul.primary-menu li:first-child a{
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}
ul#left-primary.primary-menu li .sub-menu li a {
    padding: 8px 27px 8px 35px !important;
}
ul#right-primary.primary-menu li:first-child a{
    padding: 14px 27px 16px;
}
ul#right-primary.primary-menu li:last-child a{
    padding-right: 0;
}
ul.primary-menu li a i{
 color:#dcdcde;
}

/*sub-menu*/
ul.primary-menu ul{
 font-weight:normal;
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 /*z-index:999;*/
  padding: 16px 0;
 width:250px;
 margin:0;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
ul.primary-menu li.active{
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

I bought this theme on ThemeForest.net and I also asked the same question on the support page but I doubt anybody would help me, because I've asked a question to the support team from that theme and they were not very helpful. This is a proof: themeforest.net/item/marry-me-elegant-wordpress-wedding-celebration/9011898/comments#comment_8650017

Here is my website: nikosis.mzonespace.co.uk

Comment: 1. Open Google Chrome.
2. Open 'blog' page.
3. Now, try to hover that menu.

Comment: The reported error is there, think ive found the reason why but yet to find a fix. Will make my answer in a second.

Comment: Still no issue for me...But I may be an outlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your header element has a position set to it but the `z-index` is set to the same as the content box.

The other pages use a different template which doesn't have a higher `z-index` whereas the contact and blog pages both use the same template which do.

It seems like in `layout.css`, the line for the `#header` element `z-index` has been commented out. It should look like this:

```
//line 126 - layout.css
#header{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Once that is in place, it seems like the navigation works across all pages fine.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now, everything works like a charm. What can I do  to repay you? Is there any donation button or anything? You were extremely helpful!!!

Comment: No need for money, just an accepted answer (that little tick on the left of my answer). Everyone's here just to help each other out and at the same time learn new things by trying different things out.